# Checking for res 'status' in Query Call for MariaDB

Tags: node.js, mariadb, sybase, sqlanywhere

I am rewriting some Node code to execute SQL queries via a MariaDB connector instead over via SQL Anywhere, and I'm trying to determine what response property I can latch onto to replicate the code we had before.

The old code looked like this:

```
  sybase.query("SELECT * FROM cc_customers WHERE ex_id = ?",
                [transaction.ex_id], function (result) {
    if (result.status != 'success') {
      connPoolSize++;
      transactionsLeftToProcess--;

      return;
    }...
```

Notice how we're making use of `result.status` when running a query via SQL Anywhere to a Sybase db. Now in MariaDB I'm wondering what gets returned as part of the respond that we can use to replicate this conditional check. In the documentation (https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/connector-nodejs-promise-api/#connectionquerysql-values-promise) I see reference to `res` and to `rows` being available as part of the response, but I'm not clear if `status`, or something equivalent (a status code?) gets returned as part of `res` on the query call. What properties are returned that I can use in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `MariaDB` you can simply catch the error. If you are using `async/await` it could be something like:

```
async function fetchCustommers() {
  try {
    return await mariadb.query("SELECT * FROM cc_customers WHERE ex_id = ?", [transaction.ex_id])
  } catch (error) {
    // Your status !== 'success' logic
    connPoolSize++;
    transactionsLeftToProcess--;
  }
}
```

As for a `then/catch` approach:

```
function fetchCustommers() {
  return mariadb.query("SELECT * FROM cc_customers WHERE ex_id = ?", [transaction.ex_id])
    .catch(error => {
      // Your status !== 'success' logic
      connPoolSize++;
      transactionsLeftToProcess--;
    })
}
```

Also [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/connector-nodejs-promise-api/#error) are the properties available in the `Error` instance.